# Why does my d3.js graph load so slowly during calls to d3-dag.min.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a beginner and trying to learning to use d3.js. I wrote a DAG for the classes in my comp sci curriculum, but the website loads extremely slowly (20-40 seconds consistently) despite it being not very complex. Here's the link, I would be grateful for any help!

[my project](https://jimzhou112.github.io/cs_classes_ucla/)

Comment: The website loads fine. Even though I'm having a bad internet day, it loaded in 124ms. What you mean is it's rendering slowly. To mitigate this to a background process, you can do something like `setTimeout(() => { /* call rendering function here */}, 0)`